# Windows 8 log in to Microsoft OneDrive with separate email from login?

Tags: windows, onedrive

In Windows 8.1 I log in with a different email than I use for my OneDrive. Is there anyway I can connect the One Drive to a SPECIFIC email that is NOT my normal email that I log in my computer with. I do not have this problem with Windows 7 obviously.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in Windows 8.1, but I believe you'll be able to do so in Windows 10 when it ships in July.